# How to make for loop wait until callback was successful?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, for-loop, get

```
$scope.checkwithfor = function(evlappsub){
        if( evlappsub != "" && typeof evlappsub !="undefined"){
            var s = serviceDomain + '/catanalysisdb/' + evlappsub;
            $http.get(s).success(function(data3){
                $scope.chartscore.name = data3.keyattributes.appName;
                $scope.chartscore.y = (data3.keyattributes.totalAffinity * -1);
                $scope.chartscoreval.push($scope.chartscore);
            });
        }
    }
    var serviceDomain = "url";
    if(evaluation_id !== ''){
         $http.get(serviceDomain + '/catanalysisdb/' + evaluation_id).success(function(data) {
             var evl_id = data.form.mainFields[8].fieldTypeVal;
             for(var i=0;i<evl_id.length;i++){
                 var evljsonsum_ib = evl_id[i].value;
                 evlappsub = "cat_sub_key_val_"+evljsonsum_ib.split("_")[1];
                 $scope.checkwithfor(evlappsub);
             }
         });
    }
```

- $scope.chartscoreval.push : while pushing object into array, but its contains only last object.
- $scope.checkwithfor : before i get success result of get method loop completed.

Comment: You can't use a synchronous loop with asynchronous code and expect it to work properly. Wouldn't it make more sense to make a single request, send all the values at once and have the server return a single response?

Answer (score 0):

**Use Promise**

With vanilla JavaScript (ECMAScript 5), there is no direct way to force the event loop to wait for a particular asynchronous call. But if you really need to wait for an asynchronous call to finish then proceed, use *Promise*.

***Promise is gonna be integrated to ECMAScript 6***

But there are some libraries which give you the Promise functionality. One of them is "promisejs": (You can pick any others, they are implemented to follow the same standard.)

https://www.promisejs.org/

**Also, you need to tweak your for-loop**

To chain promises which forces the asynchronous function to be done before proceed, you need to modify your for-loop to get this mission possible.

```
$scope.checkwithfor = function(evlappsub){
    return new Promise(function(fulfill,reject){
       if( evlappsub != "" && typeof evlappsub !="undefined"){
           var s = serviceDomain + '/catanalysisdb/' + evlappsub;
           $http.get(s).success(function(data3){
               $scope.chartscore.name = data3.keyattributes.appName;
               $scope.chartscore.y = (data3.keyattributes.totalAffinity * -1);
               $scope.chartscoreval.push($scope.chartscore);
               fulfill(); // SIGNIFY IT'S DONE!
           });
        } 
    });
}
var serviceDomain = "url";
if(evaluation_id !== ''){
     $http.get(serviceDomain + '/catanalysisdb/' + evaluation_id).success(function(data) {
         var evl_id = data.form.mainFields[8].fieldTypeVal;

         // FORMER LOOP ACTION
         function checkEvl(i){
             if (i<evl_id.length){
                 var evljsonsum_ib = evl_id[i].value;
                 evlappsub = "cat_sub_key_val_"+evljsonsum_ib.split("_")[1];
                 $scope.checkwithfor(evlappsub).then(function(){
                     // AFTER FINISH, CALL THE NEXT EVL
                     checkEvl(i+1);
                 });
             }
         }

         checkEvl(0); // STARTS OFF WITH THE FIRST ELEMENT
     });
}
```

> **Additional explanation**
>
> You need to substitute your *for-loop* with a recursive function.
>   With this, you can repeatedly invoke a function immediately after a promise 
>   acknowledge a `done` signal via `fulfill()`.
>
> **So the process flow will roughly looks like below**:
>
> checkEvl(0) ⇒ checkwithfor() ⇒ fulfill() ⇒ then() ⇒ checkEvl(1) ⇒ ...

Comment: there is anyother option to achieve in plain javascript or angularjs.

Comment: Angularjs also comes with promise. Instead of standard `new Promise(function(fulfill,reject){})` you can do `$q(function(fulfill, reject){})` . See this: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q